# Alliance Cruiser in Border Space

Tags: firefly

In the Blue Sun expansion, there is a border space card that places Alliance cruiser alert tokens on *every* sector with an outlaw ship, in resolving the alert tokens the Alliance cruiser may end up having to move the cruiser to a sector outside of Alliance space. Is this an accurate reading of the rules, given that it results in the Alliance cruiser in either border or rim space?

And then, if this is the case after this happens, how does the Alliance cruiser move after this when directed to move 1 space within Alliance space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reavers may never move to Alliance space, and the Cruiser can never move to Reaver space.

If they can't move to the space, nothing happens.

But note that in the Kalidasa expansion, there is an Operative's *Corvette* that can move everywhere, and would use the tokens in that situation.